# Mysql remote connection address

Tags: java, mysql

I'm connecting to a mysql remote address. Though I get an error that the port has to be specified but I already have it here?

```
 Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://http://185.27.134.10:3306","username","password");
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the 'http://' schema.

```
 Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://185.27.134.10:3306","username","password");
```

[The docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)

Comment: Cool, do me a favor and still post the stacktrace you were getting from the error. That way it could help others in the future.

Comment: I didn't get any stacktrace. i got a Connection Driver exception saying: Connection needs a specified port after ':'